# Цикл JavaScript быстрее цикла PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день.
Сегодня спортивного интереса ради решил проверить, насколько php быстрее javascript, т.к. я всегда считал, что php быстрее.

Сделал 2 одинаковых цикла на обоих языках, результат меня удивил.

JavaScript:

```
var start = new Date();

var x=0;
for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++){
    x++;
}

var end = new Date();
console.log('Скорость ' + (end.getTime()-start.getTime()) + ' мс');
```

PHP:

```
$begin_time = time() - 1272000000 + floatval(microtime());

$x=0;
for($i=0;$i<10000000;$i++){
    $x++;
}

$end_time = time() - 1272000000 + floatval(microtime()) - $begin_time;
echo $end_time;
```

Всё делалось на денвере на одной машине.

Результаты:

Во всех браузерах PHP посчитал цикл за 1.05 секунды. А вот яваскрипт оказался шустрее (ну естественно IE подкачал)

Firefox:
JS = 33 мс

Chrome:
JS = 149 мс

Opera:
JS = 37мс

IE:
JS = 606мс )))

Safari:
JS = 137мс

В файрфоксе JS оказался быстрее php в 33 раза. Это нормальное явление? Меня просто удивил такой расклад :)

Comment: Как-то не по-русски.  

    time() - 1272000000 + floatval(microtime())

Лучше  

    microtime(1)

Comment: Причиной тому не то, что одно исполняется на сервер, а второе на клиенте.. Причина здесь очень проста - JS няша, а PHP - какаша :D

Comment: @AlexWindHope, фу таким быть =/

Comment: А теперь добавь в эксперимент обращение к БД или чтение/запись файлов

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript выполняется на стороне клиента, а PHP скрипт на стороне сервера.

Вы что с чем сравниваете молодой человек?! С тем же успехом можно сравнивать длину юбочки блондинки с шинелью полковника...

Comment: A node js?)

Comment: У блондинки юбка короче по-любому. 
По поводу JS: суммарно **мощность компьютеров клиентов превосходит мощность сервера**, так что в разумных пределах **меет смысл загружать именно клиента** работой, с которой он вполне в состоянии справиться. Другое дело, еще остались люди, которые бьют себя пяткой в грудь и уверяют, что обязательно надо поддерживать слоупоков, у которых !!Внимание!! ОТКЛЮЧЕН JS. Именно отключен, а не отсутствует. Для таких есть <noscript>.

Comment: Barmaley, сервер и клиент = одна и та же моя машина )
говорю же, на денвере всё держится

Comment: Я стараюсь без нужды не включать js в браузер. И что? Кричать, что достали уроды, которые на ровном месте в свои идиотские страницы лепят джаваскрипт?

Comment: А с каких это пор стало зазорным сравнивать производительность различных ЯП? Тем более, что оба могут выполнять схожие задачи. Т.ч. я считаю, что сравнение вполне корректное, хоть и с предсказуемыми результатами.

Что же касается задач выполняемых и на сервере, и на клиенте, то тут можно придумать много сценариев. Например, самый очевидный - это генерация HTML по шаблону.

Comment: За что так много плюсов? LOL

Comment: @AlexWindHope ну ясен пень - плюсы за блондинку :)

Comment: @Barmaley, надо было размер бюста сравнивать, плюсов больше бы было :)

Comment: И это лучший ответ? Он в корне неверен.

Answer (score 2):

> Во всех браузерах PHP посчитал цикл за 1.05 секунды.

Вы правда считаете, что скорость обработки запроса web сервером зависит от браузера? :)

А в целом тест не совсем корректный.
Если не брать в учёт, что сравнительное тестирование скорости интерпретатора PHP и движков Javascript вызывает "логическое недомогание" головного мозга, Вы хотя бы выполните скрипт нативно - без веб серверов.

Comment: перестарались вы с употреблением таким умных фраз и слов. я вас нихрена не понял

Comment: Не утруждайтесь, вряд ли это повлияет на результат

Comment: @activist - я выполнял тесты "нативно", без браузерной оболочки для JS и без веб-сервера для PHP, результаты практически такие-же (+- 5%)

Answer (score -1):

> сервер и клиент = одна и та же моя машина )

И что из этого?

На php у тебя отводится 30 метров памяти и 30-60 секунд времени, а JS на стороне клиента будет хавать все возможные ресурсы которые есть на компе.

Да и вообще как-то бредово сравнивать серверное и клиентское исполнение.

Что нужно выполнить на сервере, ни в жизни не отдашь на исполнение клиенту! ИМХО!

Comment: Бредово требовать ресурсы, если речь об вычислении суммы в цикле. Т.о. реализация ПХП это бред.

Comment: Лениво было комментировать вопрос но, раз приняли такой ответ...

@Shrek - несмотря на то, что ваше утверждение бредово по всем критериям, допустим что причина такого результата PHP в том, что он зависит от апача, в том что ему мало памяти и т.д.

Собственно - запустите интерпритатор напрямую и Вы увидите, что причина такого результата элементарна до безобразия и заключается в убогости реализации PHP.

Если есть сомнения по поводу браузерного окружения - не поленитесь поставьте node.js и проведите тест, результат будет примерно таким-же...

Comment: Я имею введу - запустите оба теста с консоли.

Единственное в чем вы правы( но непосредственно к вопросу это не имеет практически никакого отношения ), так это в том, что то, что нужно выполнить на сервере, ни в жизни не отдашь на исполнение клиенту.

По поводу бредово сравнивать клиент и сервер - не забываем о node.js.
Запустите тест на node.js и результаты будут примерно такими-же.

PS: мне понравилась часть ответа про оперативную память - не могли бы вы написать где тут по Вашему нужно даже тех-же 30 метров?

Comment: На самом деле, ответ был рассчитан на последние строчки.

>Лениво было комментировать вопрос но, раз приняли такой ответ...

А не поверишь как мне лениво комментировать то что его приняли :)

Будет свободный день поставлю и протестирую.честно, пока его нет.

Comment: Результаты будут примерно такими-же, в любом случае - php **намного медленнее**

Comment: php медленнее - разумно и правда :), я и не спорю.

Comment: > Единственное в чем вы правы( но непосредственно к вопросу это не имеет практически никакого отношения ), так это в том, что то, что нужно выполнить на сервере, ни в жизни не отдашь на исполнение клиенту.

И это говорит человек пропагандирующий Node.js?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, [AlexWindHope Node.js](https://www.google.ru/search?q=AlexWindHope+%22node.js%22+site%3Ahashcode.ru)

PS Я вовсе не в укор это сказал. Мне самому симпатизирует Node.js и во многом именно из-за возможности тесной интеграции клиентской и серверной части.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov - спс, занятная ссылка :D

Попробуйте заменить node.js на php, ссылок будет намного больше, но это никак не говорит о том, что я его люблю :D

PS: пытался вставить нормальную ссылку, но так и не смог...

Comment: У меня разрыв шаблонов, прекратите. @IlyaPirogov, что не так с NodeJS? Он по вашему не может выполнить код на сервере? Или как? V8 действительно шустрее php, при чём тут всё остальное вообще?